# Can't make a caml query works for a boolean

Tags: 2010, caml-query, csom, caml

I try to take the elemtens in a list where the field "Mise à jour parc" is set to "No" with the boolean type.

My field 'Mise à jour parc" has for db name for sharepoint "Mise_x0020__x00e0__x0020_jour_x0"

Here is my query code with the query:

```
var collListItemToBeUpdatedReventeMaj = "";
var numOccurrencesMajRevente = 0;
var enumeratorRevente;
function getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeMaj() //this function called on button click to get ID's
{
     collListItemToBeUpdatedReventeMaj = "";
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Matériel revente finale');
     var camlQueryReventeMaj = new SP.CamlQuery();
     camlQueryReventeMaj.set_viewXml("<View> <Query> <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Mise_x0020__x00e0__x0020_jour_x0'> <Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value> </FieldRef> </Eq> </Where> </Query> </View> ");
     collListItemToBeUpdatedReventeMaj = oList.getItems(camlQueryReventeMaj);
     clientContext.load(collListItemToBeUpdatedReventeMaj);
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess1ReventeMaj, getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed1ReventeMaj);
}
function getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess1ReventeMaj()
{

    numOccurrencesMajRevente = collListItemToBeUpdatedReventeMaj.get_count();
    setValue2();            
}
function getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed1ReventeMaj(sender, args)
{
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}



    function setValue2() {

        $("#revente_count").text(numOccurrencesMajRevente).toString();
    }
```

I always go in the failed. I tried :

```
"<View> <Query> <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Mise_x0020__x00e0__x0020_jour_x0'> <Value Type='Boolean'>False</Value> </FieldRef> </Eq> </Where> </Query> </View> "

"<View> <Query> <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Mise_x0020__x00e0__x0020_jour_x0'> <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value> </FieldRef> </Eq> </Where> </Query> </View> "

"<View> <Query> <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Mise_x0020__x00e0__x0020_jour_x0'> <Value Type='Text'>No</Value> </FieldRef> </Eq> </Where> </Query> </View> "

"<View> <Query> <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Mise_x0020__x00e0__x0020_jour_x0'> <Value Type='Bool'>0</Value> </FieldRef> </Eq> </Where> </Query> </View> "
```

I'm sure FieldRef is good because without the Value, I have the number for all items.

An idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CAML would look like:

```
<Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='booleanField' />
         <Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value>
      </Eq>    
</Where>
```

If you are going to be building a lot of CAML queries, I'd highly recommend picking up the CAML Designer from http://www.biwug.be/resources.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake was with the FieldRef that I closed after the value